# SonarQube: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Tags: python, sonarqube

I am trying to analise Python code using SonarQube 8.9.1 with sonar-runner 2.4.
When I run

```
/opt/sonar-runner-2.4/bin/sonar-runner -X
```

I get the following result:

```
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 11.0.11 Ubuntu (64-bit)
Linux 5.4.0-80-generic amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: /opt/sonar-runner-2.4/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /data/Projects/momentum-git/AppsAws/RiskLambdaPoc/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_ZA", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /data/Projects/momentum-git/AppsAws/RiskLambdaPoc/./.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 8.9.1.44547
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.365s
Final Memory: 1M/17M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.dowloadFiles(Jars.java:78)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.download(Jars.java:57)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:46)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.checkVersionAndDownload(JarDownloader.java:37)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:71)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.dowloadFiles(Jars.java:72)
        ... 12 more
```

When I analyze Java 1.8 code using the org.sonarqube Gradle plugin version (org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2) it works fine.

But not with my Python code.

Please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing sonar-runner with sonar-scanner solved the problem.
Download and config can be found [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/)